# Form validation not working in mdDialog

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple working `form`, but when I put this in a `$mdDialog` it doesn't disable the submit button anymore... it basically ignores the `networktypeForm.$invalid` Is this common or is there a fix for this?

```
<form name="networktypeForm" ng-submit="add()" novalidate role="form">
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
      <md-input-container md-no-float flex>
        <label>Element type</label>
        <input flex ng-model="type" name="networktype" type="text" required="">
        <div ng-messages="networktypeForm.networktype.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <md-button type="submit" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-disabled="networktypeForm.$invalid">
        Add
      </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
```

Comment: use ng-class instead of ng-disabled

Comment: ng-class="{disable: networktypeForm.$invalid}" and set your disable class css to disable the batton

Comment: Not working. It's the `$invalid` that `$mdDialog` seems not being able to handle it..

Answer (score 1):

your requireds should be like this `required` not `required=""` or `required="required"`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, not working either. The form works when it's outside an `$mdDialog`

Comment: @Greg try `required="required"`

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking at this, I had a similar issue and mine was solved by removing the "novalidate" attribute.